# Can someone call themselves Dr. so and so (ABD)?

Tags: titles, all-but-dissertation

Someone in my profession is referring to themselves as Dr. so and so (ABD). It is my understanding that they are not a Dr. since they have not completed the dissertation process. Doesn't it seem fraudulent to refer to yourself as Dr. without completing a doctoral program?

Comment: Yeah, it's obviously misleading, since "the thesis" is not a trifling matter. But there are (in the U.S., as far as I know) no clear "legal" rules about such references (in contrast to precise laws in Germany, apparently).

Comment: Just an FYI (ABD) means All But Dissertation.

Comment: Looks like a dupe of four other questions today...

Comment: By the way: it may not be fraud in a legal sense, even if the person has not completed a doctoral program. Not all jurisdictions have laws controlling use of the title "Dr."

Comment: Have some fun with this.  You can call him Dr ABD forevermore.

Comment: Take it up with Dr. Dre

Comment: ^ Haha and Dr. Pepper! I did look this up and people were discussing ABD but I wanted to be sure that they are inappropriately referring to themselves as "Dr.". It is being used as their outlook signature. I actually thought they were a PhD and was just trying to figure out of what until I came across this informative web site and found out that they are not a PhD.

Comment: It absolutely depends on the jurisdiction. In the UK almost all the medical physicians one ever sees DO NOT have any kind of doctorate (they usually have two Bachelor's degrees: in medicine and surgery), yet they are always called by the title Dr.  Surgeons might well have doctorates but are addressed as Mr. Dentists used to be called Mr, like surgeons, but I notice nowadays that many prefer to be called Dr.  There is no law governing the use of the title Dr in the UK.

Answer (score 10):

Yep, can't do that. Either you do or you don't have the "Dr." and if you're ABD, you don't.